# Mongoose querying to any collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array `models` with all the model names in my project. I get any of the model name in `request.params.model`. I also get some data in `request.body`. Now all I wanted to do is insert the data received into the collection pointed by `request.params.model`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used model method of mongoose to achieve this. Below is a sample mongoose query.

```
require("mongoose").model(req.params.model).create(req.body, function(err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
```